# How will I ever be able to comment if I need a 50 reputation

Tags: discussion

Reputation is soooo frustrating.
I wanted to answer someone's follow-on question to: `https://serverfault.com/questions/54736/how-to-check-if-a-library-is-installed?newreg=c0680b11d24d4d77bfb373f3c184cf93`, which was 'how do I do this in aptitude'

I just wanted to comment:
`aptitude show libssl-dev` which on ubuntu, gives a much better result than any of the 11 years of accumulated  answers I saw, few of which worked on my Ubuntu 20.04 LTS system.:

```
% aptitude show libssl-dev
Package: libssl-dev                      
Version: 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1
State: installed
Automatically installed: no
Multi-Arch: same
Priority: optional
Section: libdevel
Maintainer: Ubuntu Developers <ubuntu-devel-discuss@lists.ubuntu.com>
Architecture: amd64
Uncompressed Size: 8,006 k
Depends: libssl1.1 (= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1)
Suggests: libssl-doc
Conflicts: libssl1.0-dev
Breaks: libssl-dev:i386 (!= 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1)
Replaces: libssl-dev:i386 (< 1.1.1f-1ubuntu2.1)
Description: Secure Sockets Layer toolkit - development files
 This package is part of the OpenSSL project's implementation of the SSL and TLS cryptographic protocols for secure communication over
 the Internet. 
 
 It contains development libraries, header files, and manpages for libssl and libcrypto.
Homepage: https://www.openssl.org/
```

Its frustrating that across all the fractured stackexchange communities, that reputation is so hard to build, that it isn't worth my time confecting a reputation to give a simple and correct comment. Surely these forums tend towards being echo-chambers because of this.

I can't tag this with 'meta' or 'reputation' because I'd need a 500 reputation to do so. I can't ask a question in the meta forum, because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: "_reputation is so hard to build_" Not really. It is just five up votes (ask a good question, give a good answer, even to your own question), 25 approved edits to existing posts (two points each), etc. Getting 50 points is not all that hard.

Comment: See also [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/214173/189912)

Comment: "I can't ask a question in the meta forum, because I don't have enough reputation." - really?! How much rep is reqd to post on meta? I didn't think it required any (since that does rather defeat the point of meta)?

Answer (score 9):

The reputation requirements exist largely to provide at least a small chance that new users will have learnt the basics of how to use the site before they're given extra privileges.  The fact that you wanted to answer a question posed in a comment, when that isn't what comments are for, suggests that the system is working as designed.

Answer (score 0):

Just look at the "reputation guidelines" or "badges" area... you can literally get more than enough points, just by following the basic badge information, there.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this restriction is for users that are new to all of Stack Exchange and not to users that are new to this specific site.

Find one or more SE sites where you *can* ask or answer questions with confidence and build up some reputation there.

Once you reach some level (200 points in total I think), you'll automatically get 100 points on each site that your account is linked to.

And from then on, for any new site you join, you'll start off with 100 points.